# TypeError: <X> is not a function when using imported function after webpack

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

When I push my module to npm, then import it into another application, I get `TypeError: <myModule> is not a function`.

Is my issue actually with webpack or with the way I am declaring / using my imported function when it is bundled via webpack? or the way I am using babel-loader?

DETAILS:

When myModule's package.json has `"main":"src/index.js"` which is the pre-webpacked version, it works.  When I change it to `"main":"dist/index.js"` I get the issue.

I'm trying to use it like this:

`import { myModule } from '@myNPM/myModuleInNPM'
    ...
async function someFunction(stuff) {
    const scooby = await myModule(stuff)
    ...
}`

my webpack config:

```js
var path = require('path')
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  target: 'node',
  mode: 'production',
  optimization: {
    // We do not want to minimize our code.
    minimize: false
  },
  performance: {
    // Turn off size warnings for entry points
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: 'nosources-source-map',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index.js'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found my answer...  I needed to specify my libraryTarget in my webpack config.   I am now using `libraryTarget: 'commonjs'` an it works beautifully